# How to search for Amazon SageMaker Models using Tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy, aws-codeartifact

When I open the Model details in the Amazon SageMaker console,(Amazon SageMaker->Inference->Models), the details clearly show Tags that have been added to the model during it's creation.

[Tag details in the Amazon SageMaker Models console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iasM4.png)

But the Search API provided by Amazon SageMaker, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_Search.html

mentions only the following resources can be searched for using Tags:

> Valid Values: TrainingJob | Experiment | ExperimentTrial |
> ExperimentTrialComponent | Endpoint | ModelPackage | ModelPackageGroup
> | Pipeline | PipelineExecution | FeatureGroup | Project |
> FeatureMetadata

I wish to obtain Model details, not the ModelPackageGroup/ModelPackage details, using Tags so if there is a way to do that, please share. Also if there is no way to obtain it using Tags, like the Search API Documentation suggests, what is the purpose of the Tags still present in the Model details?

Answer (score 0):

Models in SageMaker are not searchable through the Search API.

You can use the Tags API to find your resources based on Tag values - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html